# How to read an asbestos report

Tags: asbestos

Someone help me out here. I had 3 samples taken as labeled on the results. I'm finding it difficult to decipher the report from the lap.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You took 3 samples and sent them in.  #1 and #2 contain no asbestos.  The third sample does indeed contain Chrystoile, or white asbestos.  From [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chrysotile)

> Chrysotile or white asbestos is the most commonly encountered form of asbestos,accounting for approximately 95% of the asbestos in the United States.

Of that layer within the third sample where it was positively detected, it is about 8% asbestos (visually estimated) and 92% non-fibrous components (difference of 100% - 8%) that the lab did not further analyze.  In the third sample, there were 3 layers and the layer containing asbestos made up 90% of that sample.

Comment: Thank you! This makes perfect sense!


That 3rd sample was from floor tiles affixed to concrete in a kitchen we want to gut. They are very hard, and not flexible at all. They appear to be brittle and easily crumble. But, it looks like they will come off easily. We want to remove them so we can tile the floor.


How dangerous is this scenario for removal as far as asbestos floor tiles go? I mean, only 8% asbestos? Seems low. But, i'm assuming all precautions are to be taken? I am familiar with typical abatement processes and have the means to do it. Just want to know how bad is the situation.

Comment: I'm not sure what percentage you will find in other scenarios, but in most cases we're talking about products made with asbestos, not made entirely of asbestos, so it's unlikely you'd find something that is 100%.  This is really a question for an expert...

Comment: That's a good point.... ahhhh.... well. As they say on How I Met Your Mother: Suit up!

Comment: Or as they say call a company that specializes in this area.

Comment: Now that you know you have asbestos, you will need to find out what the regulations are for your area.  For example in my area, you can not hire out any help/contractors unless they are licensed for asbestos abatement.  But a home owner and one family member can do the work if they dispose of the asbestos properly.

Comment: Regulation here is: Less than one cubic yard per household. Just throw it the dumpster, double bagged. Anything more than that, you have to get it certified and pay a company.

It's a kitchen. We are deciding between removal and covering with cork floor. If I remove, there's no way I'm paying another company. It's pretty much a scam here. They won't follow proper procedures but they'll charge you like they are. And anyway, it's not that difficult to do yourself.

If I remove, I am basically following this procedure: http://www.health.state.mn.us/divs/eh/asbestos/floortile/